# Обновление DataGrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid, linq2sql

Работаю с LINQ TO SQL. При вызове функции **DeleteOnSubmit(Data.SelectedItem as User);** и **DataContext.SubmitChanges();** из DataGrid не удаляется элемент. При этом из базы данных и элемента **Table** он уже удален (видно по отладчику). Как обновить корректно информацию в DataGrid?

Comment: MVVM используете?

Comment: @Alexandr - нет, пока еще не пользуюсь.

Comment: @Andrey1512 тогда удалять надо еще и из отображаемой коллекции. кажется это ItemsSource (но это не точно)

Comment: `MyDataGrid.Items.Refresh()`

Comment: @Alexandr уже пробовал, System.InvalidOperationException: "Операция недопустима, когда ItemsSource используется. Вместо этого получите доступ и измените элементы с помощью ItemsControl.ItemsSource."

Comment: @Андрей NOP, пробовал так же. Не помогает, ничего не происходит :(

Comment: А как вы данные в DataGrid выводите? Покажите код

Comment: @Андрей NOP, Простой привязкой: DataGrid.ItemsSource = Players; Players - это таблица (Table<Player> Players; DataContext.GetTable<Player>();). Что интересно - по отладчику прохожу - при удалении в таблице Players после SubmitChanges(); пропадает элемент. А в DataGrid он по прежнему висит...

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx попробуйте это или как вариант после удаления делать itemsource = null; itemsource = "снова запрос в таблицу"

Answer (score 0):

Можно заново загрузить данные с базы в таблицу. И присвоить в `ItemsSource` заново.

Но советую попробовать `ObservableCollection` с `INotifyPropertyChanged`